# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, classnotfoundexception

I downloaded Jsoup and it gives me this error when I run code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at Nick.Nickname.onCommand(Nickname.java:58) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at Nick.Nickname.onCommand(Nickname.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        ... 15 more
```

There's no errors on the code

`

Comment: welcome to SO. Please review how to ask a good question on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You should include your sample code for others to be able to help

Comment: Downloaded from where? How are you running the code? Do you understand what a classpath is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you run your code, so we need further information on that.

You are actually getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` which means that the `org.jsoup.Jsoup` class definition was present at compile time, but during runtime when you try to instantiate it, it was not.

See this helpful article for [the differences between ClassNotFoundException & NoClassDefFoundError](https://dzone.com/articles/java-classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderro) , and you may be able to find the root cause of your error,

Answer (score 0):

please check the below things to resolve your issues.

1. did you add required jar/class files into your project's build path(library) ?
2. does the referenced jar/class folder contains the required **Jsoup** class in the package **org.jsoup.Jsoup** ?
3. check whether your referenced library is included in build, if your building your project like jar, war, etc,.
4. check markers tab for errors if you are using eclipse.